# What're the main similarities (in terms of major plot points) between the 1983 and 2009 versions of V?

Tags: v-2009, v-1983

I've seen some of the new series, but I didn't realise it was a remake.

Are there any similarities remaining from the remake ?

I'm only concerned about major plot points. For instance from what I've read on the wiki,  in the remake the visitors use the youth as spies. It's that sort of plot point in interested in.

Comment: this could be seen as slightly opinion-based maybe - what counts as a *main* difference? Perhaps you could elaborate. Otherwise the question might be deemed too broad.

Comment: It is a very broad topic. They are as different as the 1978 and 2004 versions of Battlestar Galactica.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister I've flipped it round, is that any better?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I still think it's too broad because what kinds of things are you looking for? Different characters, plots, sub-plots, themes etc.? Answers are going to be incredibly long and yet still could be incomplete.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister how about now?  Or do you think it's unsalvageable?

Comment: Now it starting to sound like a "list" question. IMHO, the best thing about the 1983 version was it's depiction of just how *easy* it is for a repressive fascist government to arise even here in [Eagleland.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Eagleland)

Comment: A bit better. @JoeL. list questions aren't necessarily off-topic, so long as the parameters are clearly and appropriately defined. Two series that have both finished should have a finite number of items to list. I'll admit I've watched neither series so I will now leave it to others to answer and/or comment if they think the question is still not clear enough.